# How to print a return value of a method in a class?

Tags: python, class, printing

I was working on an online tutorial on class in python, then I wanted to try to make a function that print out the value in the return of the other functions. Here is the code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Vehicle(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    base_sale_price = 0
    wheels = 0

    def __init__(self, miles, make, model, year, sold_on):
        self.miles = miles
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.sold_on = sold_on

    def sale_price(self):
        if self.sold_on is not None:
            return 0.0
        return 5000.0 * self_wheels

    def purchase_price(self):
        if self.sold_on is None:
            return 0.0
        return self.base_sale_price - (.10 * self.miles)

    def spec(self):
        x = self.sale_price
        y = self.purchase_price

        print "This car should sell at: ", x 
        print "This car should be bought at: ", y

    @abstractmethod
    def vehicle_type():
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):

    base_sale_price = 8000.0
    wheel = 4

    def vehicle_type(self):
        return 'car'

class Truck(Vehicle):

    base_sale_price = 10000.0
    wheels = 4

    def vehicle_type(self):
        return 'truck'

AE86 = Truck(4, 35000, 'Toyota', 'AE86', 1986, )
print AE86.sale_price()
```

This is what I get: 
`This car should sell at:  <bound method Truck.sale_price of  <__main__.Truck object at 0x10666da50>>
This car should be bought at:  <bound method Truck.purchase_price of <__main__.Truck object at 0x10666da50>>`

What am I doing wrong? how do I make the return value of the methods to show up??

Comment: If you want the value, you need to actually call the method self.sale_price(), your are just assigning the method object to x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have a typo in `def sale_price(self):`

`return 5000.0 * self.wheels` not `return 5000.0 * self_wheels`

in `def spec(self):` you are not calling the class methods, you want.

```
def spec(self):
    x = self.sale_price()
    y = self.purchase_price()
    print "This car should sell at: ", x 
    print "This car should be bought at: ", y
```

Comment: OHHHH that's the reason! I'm still new to coding and understanding function is still challenging. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help, you can read more about functions in the [python tutorial page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) but basically if you can assign functions to variables, so if I have a function `foo` and set `bar=foo` you can call the function with `bar()`. This is useful if you want to pass a function as a parameter to another function.
Also if you can mark questions as answered on StackOverflow more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)